# Display speed on the video while capturing in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, video-capture

I want to do something as follows.

When user is capturing the video from his iPhone 3G, 3GS and iphone4, he should be able to show some data on the screen which will be captured on the video it self, so when we will see the video again, he will be able to see the video along with data on screen.

Like for example we can say I want to display the speed of the vehicle when video was being captured. So when user will see this video after words, he should be able to see the speed on the video it self.

Is this possible in iPhone??? or any body having other ideas for this.

Thanks in advance...

Regards,
VIshaL

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create some sort of dynamic video overlay.

This is your single best bet towards what you are asking, but I am unsure if it will lead you to the result you need as it may be too dynamic in nature.

http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/10/custom-video-overlay-view-on-the-iphone/

I hope this helps.